# Make component width independent from text length

Tags: android, android-textureview

How to make `TextView`'s to be same width in `TableRow` even text in one of the views is much bigger?

```
    <TableRow
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="Temperature"
            android:gravity="center"
            ></TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="Temperatureccccccccccccccccccccccccc"
            android:gravity="center"
            ></TextView>


    </TableRow>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width of your `TextView` to some fixed value. If you don't want the additional text to go to next line limit the number of lines using `maxLines` attribute.

NOTE: Be careful when you use fixed-width. The text size can change based on device settings irrespective of the text size you specify, so the text may not be visible completely if your text view has fixed size, and user's device settings use a large text size.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Temperatureccccccc" />
```

Sample Output:

Without `maxLines` attribute

[image: Output 1]

With `maxLines` attribute

[image: Output 2]

If you want to take the space equally use `layout_weight` property. It divides available space equally among two text views. Make sure to set the `layout_width` to 0dp.

```
<TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Temperature" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Temperaturecccccffffffffffffffcc" />
        </TableRow>
```

Sample Output:

[image]